# O arquivo WFA1.exe não é um PE (executável portátil) válido

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

Olá,

Estou tentando utilizar a função de update do visual studio utilizando o Click Once, porém em alguns computadores, ao começar a instalação do arquivo, o mesmo trava e exibe uma mensagem de erro.

Este problema só ocorre com alguns computadores, já testei inclusive com a mesma versão do SO onde ocorre o erro em outro computador e o mesmo funcionou normalmente.

Pelo que eu pesquisei, poderia ser a falta do net flamework, porém o computador já possui ele instalado.

Alguém teria alguma ideia do que pode ser, visto que em vários computadores ele funciona normalmente?

Obs: O computador não possui anti vírus.

Segue o log do erro

> INFORMAÇÕES SOBRE VERSÕES DE PLATAFORMAS  Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536
>   (Win32NT)     Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
>     System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>     clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR     dfdll.dll           :
>   4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR     dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)
>
> ORIGENS   URL da Implantação          :
>   http://site.com.br:8081/WFA1.application
>                         Servidor        : Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)    URL do Provedor de Implantação      : http: //site. com. br:8081/WFA1.application   URL do
>   Aplicativo            :
>   http: //site. com.br: 
>   8081/Application%20Files/WFA1_1_0_0_0/WFA1.exe.manifest
>                         Servidor        : Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
>
> IDENTIDADES   Identidade da Implantação       : WFA1.application,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=pt-BR, PublicKeyToken=9bf469c2b60e30df,
>   processorArchitecture=msil    Identidade do Aplicativo        : WFA1.exe,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=pt-BR, PublicKeyToken=9bf469c2b60e30df,
>   processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
>
> RESUMO DO APLICATIVO  * Aplicativo instalável.
>
> RESUMO DOS ERROS  Um resumo dos erros pode ser encontrado a seguir. Os
>   detalhes desses erros são relacionados posteriormente no log.     *
>   Exceção na ativação de http: //site. com. br: 8081/WFA1.application. As
>   seguintes mensagens de erro foram detectadas:         + Exceção ao carregar
>   o manifesto do arquivo WFA1.exe: talvez o manifesto não seja válido ou
>   o arquivo não pôde ser aberto.        + O arquivo WFA1.exe não é um PE
>   (executável portátil) válido.         + O arquivo PE não possui dados
>   suficientes.
>
> RESUMO DA FALHA DA TRANSAÇÃO DE ARMAZENAMENTO DO COMPONENTE   Nenhum
>   erro de transação foi detectado.
>
> AVISOS    Não houve avisos durante esta operação.
>
> STATUS DO ANDAMENTO DA OPERAÇÃO   * [20/06/2016 11:53:53] : A ativação
>   de http://site.com.br:8081/WFA1.application foi iniciada.     *
>   [20/06/2016 11:53:58] : O processamento do manifesto da implantação
>   foi concluído com êxito.  * [20/06/2016 11:53:58] : A instalação do
>   aplicativo foi iniciada.  * [20/06/2016 11:53:58] : O processamento do
>   manifesto do aplicativo foi concluído com êxito.  * [20/06/2016
>   11:54:01] : Encontrada versão 4.0.30319 do runtime compatível.    *
>   [20/06/2016 11:54:01] : A solicitação de confiança e de detecção da
>   plataforma foi concluída.
>
> DETALHES DOS ERROS    Os erros a seguir foram detectados durante esta
>   operação.     * [20/06/2016 11:56:11]
>   System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException
>   (ManifestLoad)
>         - Exceção ao carregar o manifesto do arquivo WFA1.exe: talvez o manifesto não seja válido ou o arquivo não pôde ser aberto. 
>         - Origem: System.Deployment
>         - Rastreamento de pilha:            em System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception
>   exception, String filePath)           em
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String
>   filePath)             em
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object
>   sender, DownloadEventArgs e)          em
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, DownloadEventArgs e)          em
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)             em
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>             em
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>   subState)             em
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState
>   subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest
>   appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)          em
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>   TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          em
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          em
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             em
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)        --- Exceção interna ---         System.IO.IOException
>         - O arquivo WFA1.exe não é um PE (executável portátil) válido.
>         - Origem: System.Deployment
>         - Rastreamento de pilha:            em System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ConstructFromFile(String
>   filePath, Boolean partialConstruct)           em
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String
>   filePath)         --- Exceção interna ---         System.IO.IOException
>         - O arquivo PE não possui dados suficientes.
>         - Origem: System.Deployment
>         - Rastreamento de pilha:            em System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.PEComponent.ReadData(FileStream
>   file, Int64 position, Type dataType)          em
>   System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ResourceDirectory..ctor(ResourceSection
>   resourceSection, FileStream file, Int64 rootResourceAddress, Int64
>   resourceAddress, Int64 addressDelta, Boolean partialConstruct)            em
>   System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ResourceSection..ctor(FileStream
>   file, SectionHeader sectionHeader, Boolean partialConstruct)          em
>   System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ConstructPEImage(FileStream
>   file, Boolean partialConstruct)           em
>   System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ConstructFromFile(String
>   filePath, Boolean partialConstruct)
>
> DETALHES DA TRANSAÇÃO DE ARMAZENAMENTO DO COMPONENTE  Nenhuma
>   informação de transação está disponível.

Comment: Amigo isto não é um fórum, é uma Q&A, não poste a resposta dentro da pergunta, faça o tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e leia o help http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Corrigido, vlw o aviso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava na versão do apache instalada, bastou atualizar o mesmo.